# How do I prevent that encrypted blocks of longer message won't swap when I send it through any operation cipher mode?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, cbc-mode

How do I prevent that encrypted blocks of longer message won't swap when I send it through any operation cipher mode? So the meaning of the message after recieving won't be changed?

Comment: Authenticate the ciphertext with HMAC-SHA256 or use an authenticated mode like GCM or EAX.

Comment: You should only be concerned about malleability of ciphertext and plaintext during transport. If the blocks change position *within* a (block) cipher mode of operation then you have bigger fish to worry about.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by the fish?

Comment: What @MaartenBodewes probably means is that if the blocks are re-ordered, then you have an active attack on your hands. To answer your question: you cannot prevent reordering, but you can detect change.

Comment: Yes, I meant that if the blocks were reordered that your machine is likely compromised, which means that you are in trouble whichever way you look at it. Using a HMAC or authenticated mode is definitely the way to go. Note that this question is probably better suited to crypto.stackexchange.com, but I think it must have been answered multiple times there already. Let me check...

Comment: Ah, [here it is](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/11798/1172). Could you delete this question, you have your answer I suppose?